# What's the quickest way to capture a new face?

Tags: face-raiders

The Nintendo 3DS comes with Face Raiders, an Augmented Reality game played with pictures taken with the 3DS.  I want to get more faces for my face collection, but the new faces disappear when I lose a level.  Is there a way to get a new face to stay, without having to play a level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faces never stay if you lose a level, but there are ways to collect faces faster:

- The *Show a Friend* level is short and easy, and if you don't mind cheating you can play it without a friend.
- Once you play *Show a Friend* three times, the *Bonus Stage* is unlocked. In this stage faces fall forever and you only need to juggle and destroy one to have it considered "won".
- Leaving the *Surprise Snaps* mode on will have the camera take pictures of faces it detects while you're playing the game. This will let you get more than one new face per round.
- Finally, sometimes a UFO "captures" faces it detects in the regular 3DS camera album. You still need to play a level with them to unlock them completely, but you can take pictures when you don't have time to play and then clear the levels when you do.